# Qt QFile::size() always returns 0

Tags: c++, qt, size, qfile

I'm writing an app where I'm calling `QFile::size()` method a lot of times. It works in all but one place. I'll show that place and one which works for comparison.

**WHICH DOESN'T WORK:**

```
while(!in.atEnd())
{
    if (fileOut.size() != 0) //This "if" isn't executed. (if I change != to == it always returns 0)
    {
      out<<endl;
      qDebug() << "Size of fileOut: " << fileOut.size(); 
    }

    QString temp;
    temp = in.readLine();
    out<<temp;
}
```

**WHICH WORK:**

```
if(fileOut.size() != 0) 
{
  out<<endl;
}

QString temp = in.readLine();
out<<temp<<endl;

temp = in.readLine();
out<<temp;

while(temp[temp.length()-1] != ']')
{
    temp = in.readLine();
    out<<temp;
}
```

I was looking for a solve but I've tried all of those ways to solve this.

**EDIT/SOLVED:**
   For the sake of clarity, everything revolves around the buffor, however, after a slight analysis of the documentation, I can explain why only this piece of code did not return the correct value of `QFile::size()` and not all (none of them did not reach the size where the buffer would release the data automatically) . In all those places, `endl` was used and as the documentation says: ***Writes '\ n' to the stream and flushes the stream.*** So now everything is clear. In all other places, the `flush()` method was called, but I did not know about it. Such a short correction.
   Problem is solved, all you need to do is call flush().

Comment: Take the file size **before** you open it

Comment: Have you considered that the file may *not exist at all*?

Comment: I'm opening file before calling size(). Yes it exists (I called exists() method).

Comment: Create `QFile`, store the size in an int and then open it. Opened files report size 0 for some reason. And the IO streams always report 0, even for position, which sounds like a bug.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, but why it operates in other places? (Like one which I showed as example) I just want to check whether file is empty or not.

Comment: Probably because your while condition doesn't pass.

Comment: It pass, 'cause when I'm putting qDebug() << "Size of fileOut: " << fileOut.size(); outside if, it shows 0.

Comment: Which Qt version?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.10.1

Comment: Well, it might be a bug, I discovered that about 2 weeks ago, I wanted to return the bytes written to a file and discovered it always says 0, and the stream position is always 0 too. Then I discovered that if I closed the file, I'd get the correct size. So you probably can also get the size before you open the file.

Comment: Yes I tried pos() method also. Maybe there is other and easier way to check if the file is empty. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using some streamer to write your file. The problem is that the streamer buffers the data, it is not written immediately to the file (it usually waits until the buffer reaches some size to write it down).

The [`QFile::pos`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#pos) may not reflect the correct size neither, since it doesn't consider the data still in the buffer but not flushed to the file.

If you [`flush()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#flush) your streamer you'll have the correct size and cursor position:

```
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qfile.h>
#include <qtextstream.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QFile f("example.txt");
  qDebug() << "f.size() before opening =" << f.size(); // correct

  if (!f.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "Error: not opened!";
    return 1;
  }    

  QTextStream out(&f);
  qDebug() << "f.size() before writing =" << f.size(); // 0: file was overwritten

  out << "Hello world!\n";
  qDebug() << "f.size() after writing =" << f.size(); // may be incorrect
  qDebug() << "f.pos() after writing =" << f.pos(); // may be incorrect

  out.flush();
  qDebug() << "f.size() after flushing =" << f.size(); // correct

  f.close();
  qDebug() << "f.size() after closing =" << f.size(); // correct

  return 0;
}
```

The next example shows an even worse situation, when you may have a non-zero size but that doesn't reflect the correct one:

```
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <qfile.h>
#include <qtextstream.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QFile f("example.txt");

  if (!f.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) return 1;

  QTextStream out(&f);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) { // 10000 works for me, may be you have to increase it to see the partial write
    out << "Hello world!\n";
  }
  qDebug() << "f.size() after writing =" << f.size(); // may be incorrect
  qDebug() << "f.pos() after writing =" << f.pos(); // may be incorrect

  out.flush();
  qDebug() << "f.size() after flushing =" << f.size(); // correct

  f.close();

  return 0;
}
```

This is due to the fact mentioned above: the buffer was flushed at some point but there is some data still to be written.

Again, to be sure, flush your stream before checking the size.

---

**UPDATE:** code available at https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/blob/master/50669271-qt-qfilesize-always-returns-0/main.cpp

Comment: Ok, it works now, but I'm interested in which is the size when the bufor releases stored data? Where could I find out an information like that?

Comment: Once you flush the stream the file contains all the written data, so just use `QFile::size`

Comment: I know it. I was just curious how much data must be stored to release, because in some parts of my code, `QFile::size` works correctly. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn’t understand your question: `QTEXTSTREAM_BUFFERSIZE` is 16KB by default; [check here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/serialization/qtextstream.cpp.html)

Answer (score 2):

It is not portable to assume that file size is correct on open files that have been modified after the open. Even if you can "get it to work", it's still the wrong thing to do. When you have opened the file, you can check how big it is, and then your own code has to track how it has changed the size. You could of course patch Qt to do this tracking for you, but it'd work only as long as the file is accessed through the `QFileDevice` (i.e. `QFile` or `QSaveFile`).

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was in flag. `QIODevice::readOnly` was not always returning correct size (always 0). Changing to `QIODevice::readOnly` solved the problem.

Comment: It looks like your answer might need some more details, you've said changing to the same thing solved the problem?